# Are these SQL statements equal in terms of the output?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. Are these SQL statements equal in terms of their output?

- `Suppliers` (sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
- `Parts` (pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
- `Catalog` (sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)

SQL query #1

```
SELECT S.sid
FROM Suppliers S
WHERE S.address = '221 Packer street'
   OR S.sid IN (SELECT C.sid
                FROM Parts P, Catalog C
                WHERE P.color = 'red' AND P.pid = C.pid)
```

SQL query #2

```
SELECT S.sid
FROM Suppliers S, Parts P, Catalog C
WHERE (P.pid = C.Pid AND P.color = 'red') 
   OR (S.address = '221 Packer street')
```

Comment: In SQL 2, is there a missing condition on `S.sid` ?

Comment: I don't mean to sound flippant but couldn't you have run both queries and looked at the results to see if they're the same?

Comment: Query #2 should not be used - becuase: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The second statement is actually a perfect example why the old style joins are bad: it's missing a join condition between `suppliers` and one (or both) of the other tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not same. If Parts has multiple rows with one PID, it will return duplicate suppliers record.

Comment: Actually, the `Suppliers` table has a `CROSS JOIN` with the other 2 tables, meaning that there will be 1 entry per supplier per red part per catalogue as well as 1 entry per part per catalogue for the supplier at address `221 Packer street`.